# No date returned fro m pdo::fetch_obj

Tags: php, pdo

I am new to PHP, forgive me for my sin.

I am watching a video on creating an MVC and got to the point where it's time to pull data from the database.

I have my database created and can connect to it successfully, however running a query using the PDO::FETCH_OBJ is returning a empty array, I can't figure out why

The user class has the query as

```
        public function getUsers(){
        $this->db->query('select * from user');
        $result = $this->db->resultSet();
        return $result;
    }
```

I am preparing the SQL

```
public function query($sql){
            $this->statement = $this->dbhandler->prepare($sql);
        }
```

then calling the resultSet()

```
public function bind($parameter,$value,$type=null){
            switch (is_null($type)){
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                    break;
            }
            $this->statement->bindvalue($parameter,$value,$type);
        }
        //execute prepared statement
        public function execute(){
            return $this->statement->execute();
        }
        //return an array
        public function resultSet(){
            var_dump($this->statement);
//// this dump provides this, the query Select * from user works in mysql ////directly
////object(PDOStatement)#6 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(18) "select * //// from user" } dataarray(1) { ["users"]=> array(0) { } }
    
var_dump($this->statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
////this dump provides the following
////array(0) { } dataarray(1) { ["users"]=> array(0) { } }
        
            return $this->statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
        //return an single
        public function single(){
            return $this->statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
        //return rowcount
        public function rowcount(){
            return $this->statement->rowCount();
        }
```

any thoughts are appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You don't seem to have actually executed your prepared statement.

Comment: wouldn't the   return $this->statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); execute the prepared statement?

Comment: No, you have to explicitly execute it with `$this->statement->execute()` after you have bound any necessary parameters

Comment: Please help me understand why it works for this setup, not in a windows environment.  I watched the video, paused it to re-create it, checked lines of code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2yeK6LwSII https://github.com/Darynazar/MVCFramework